# db2 driver returns java.lang.Integer for smallint

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

```
while(rs.next()){
          Object o = rs.getObject(i);
          System.out.println(o.getClass()); //prints java.lang.Integer
}
```

The problem is that I have a smallint type in the database and the driver returns an Integer type. I am doing some logic at runtime and then trying to insert the value back in the database using the type I was previously handed by the DB.

I would like DB2 to return me a java.lang.Short, but I am not sure if thats possible.

Has anyone encountered this before and what did you do for a workaround?

The basic issue is - I have both int and smallint columns in the DB2 database and I need my java code to figure out which is which based on the result set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on the type of the Java object returned, ask the resultset for the actual database type of the column:

```
String databaseTypeName = resultSet.getMetadata().getColumnTypeName(columnIndex);
```

or

```
int sqlType = resultSet.getMetadata().getColumnType();
boolean isSmallInt = (sqlType == Types.SMALLINT);
```

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html. The javadoc is such a valuable source of information!

Comment: Tried that. The type is still integer - for both int and smallint columns.

Comment: Aha. The int value makes sense. The first call in your answer isnt helping, but the second one is.